# How to specify different location for Cassandra when using Embedded Cassandra?

Tags: embedded-cassandra

In my work environment, our CI/CD runners are not able to connect to the external Internet. How can I either provide a different URL to download `apache-cassandra-all` from (there's no 4.x version of `apache-cassandra` in Maven Central) or tell Embedded Cassandra to look in a different location? The second might be nice because I could add `apache-cassandra-all` as a test dependency and then point Embedded Cassandra at the runner's Gradle cache.